# ContourPlot3D using a Matlab function through MATLink

Tags: plotting, matlab, matlink

I have a Matlab function which accepts a 3 dimensional vector and returns a single number. I want to use this through MATLink to make a 3d plot.

A unit sphere:

```
ContourPlot3D[
 Norm[{x, y, z}, 2]^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

I now want to replace the Norm with my function:

```
myfunc= MFunction["myfunc"];
ContourPlot3D[myfunc[{x, y, z}] == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

but I get errors:

> MSet::unsupp: Unsupported data type. The expression "x" can't be converted.
>   MFunction::args: The arguments at positions {1} to "myfunc" could not be translated to MATLAB....

I am fairly certain I'm missing something obvious but I this is my first time with MATLink.

Comment: The problem is that the symbolic expression `{x,y,z}` is passed to `myfunc` before the values of `x,y,z` are substituted in.  Symbols can't be transferred no MATLAB, only numbers can.  So you get an error: *The expression "x" can't be converted.*  The solution is to use a wrapper function which will only evaluated for numerical vectors.  Unfortunately I don't have time to write an answer right now, but I'll do it a few hours later (or more likely someone else will do it sooner).  I just wanted to point you to the solution beforehand.

Comment: That would be _extremely_ helpful, thanks. I'll try to find information on it, in case I can do it myself as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the symbolic vector `{x,y,z}` is passed to the function before the values for `x`, `y` and `z` are substituted.  Symbols cannot be transferred to MATLAB, so you get an error:

```
In[1]:= Needs["MATLink`"]

In[2]:= OpenMATLAB[]

In[3]:= norm = MFunction["norm"]
Out[3]= MFunction["norm"]

In[4]:= norm[{x, y, z}]

During evaluation of In[4]:= MSet::unsupp: Unsupported data type. The expression "x" can't be converted.

During evaluation of In[4]:= MFunction::args: The arguments at positions {1} to "norm" could not be translated to MATLAB.

Out[4]= $Failed
```

If you use explicit numbers, all is fine:

```
In[5]:= norm[{1, 2, 3}]
Out[5]= 3.74166
```

You can use a wrapper function to prevent Mathematica from attempting to evaluate `norm[{x,y,z}]`.  This is a very typical situation in Mathematica and it's not specific to MATLink.  [See here for more information.](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820)

So let's make the wrapper function:

```
Clear[norm2]
norm2[x_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := norm[x]
```

Now `norm2` will only evaluate when supplied with numerical arguments, and we can avoid the error messages:

```
In[8]:= norm2[{x, y, z}]
Out[8]= norm2[{x, y, z}]

In[9]:= norm2[{3, 2, 1}]
Out[9]= 3.74166
```

The `ContourPlot3D` will work as well, with one *big* caveat:

```
ContourPlot3D[
 norm2[{x, y, z}] == 1, {x, -1.1, 1.1}, {y, -1.1, 1.1}, {z, -1.1, 1.1}, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 5]
```

You need to reduce the number of evaluations it does so significantly that the quality of the output will suffer a lot.  Otherwise it will take a very long time to evaluate.  With the default options, `ContourPlot3D` would do about *half a million* evaluations for this plot.  Unfortunately `MFunction` is not very fast at the moment, so you won't be able to complete more than a few hundred evaluations in a reasonable amount of time.

---

The reason for the bad performance is that there is a constant overhead to every call to an MFunction.  This overhead is due to limitations (and bugs :-( ) of the MATLAB Engine API that MATLink uses to communicate with MATLAB.  The overhead is considerably worse on Mac/Linux than on Windows, primarily because of the low quality implementation of the MATLAB Engine on these platforms.

As of 2014 January a rewrite of MATLink is in progress.  The next version will use a different way to communicate with MATLAB (the MEX API) and will significantly reduce this overhead, making these types of applications much more feasible.

---

This performance issue is not always a problem, but ContourPlot3D being a 3D plotting function it needs to make a very large number of evaluations (many more than a 1D or a 2D one would), so the performance problem is particularly apparent here.

As a workaround you could consider generating a large number of points (`Tuples[Range[-1.1, 1.1, 0.01], 3]`), and sending them all at once to MATLAB for processing, then sending all the result back in one go and using `ListContourPlot3D[..., Contours -> {1}]` on them.

Comment: @Szablocs I did the same but did not post due to this timing issue. Its better to get the performance related explanation from the developer himself. I am really looking forward to the update of MATLink when the communication overhead becomes really negligible. It is already a great tool but with such an update MATLink will be a killer app.

Comment: That was very helpful, thanks! Your work helped a likely publication for tomorrow, thanks a bunch again.